# docker: DIND container - how to safe changed default gateway permanently

Tags: routes, docker-in-docker

I choose option 3 in [How to configure static routes - Alpine Linux](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_configure_static_routes) creating `vi /etc/network/interface` to get

```
/ # cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto net1
iface net1 inet static
       address 10.10.8.105
       netmask 255.255.255.255   
       up route add 10.10.8.1 dev net1
       up route add default gw 10.10.8.1
```

but `rc-update add staticroute` is not available, so how can I test it?

Moreover, mounting `/etc/network/` to the host, is a good survive a restart but it configuration is not applied.